# shorten Jquery Validation script? or alternate?

Tags: jquery, validation

so my question is if this validation code can be more simple. I have 2 inputs that need to be checked before the user can use the other 3 inputs. I have used a lot of hide and show and for the validation I used a lot of if/else. So can someone help me because I am looking for how to shorten this. What I want is to make the form use able on 1 page. I tried using jquery validation plugin but no succes. Here is a fiddle link so you can try it: https://jsfiddle.net/br9603yq/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#adres").hide();
    $("#postcode").hide();
    $("#plaats").hide();
    $("#click2").hide();
    $("#edit").hide();
    $("#submit").hide();

    //Hide divs with class hidden
    $("div.hidden").hide();

    $("#click1").click(function() {
        var naam = $("#name").val();

        // Check if name has class verplicht and if name input isn't empty.
        if ($('#name').hasClass('verplicht') && $('#name').val() != "") {
            var email = $('#mail').val();
            var filter = (/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/);
            //if e-mail matches filter
            if (filter.test(email)) {
                $("#adres").show();
                $("#postcode").show();
                $("#plaats").show();
                $("#click2").show();
                $("#click1").hide();

                //When click2 is clicked
                $("#click2").click(function() {
                    var adres = $("#adresVeld").val();
                    var postcode = $("#postcodeVeld").val();
                    var plaats = $("#plaatsVeld").val();

                    //Double validation for naam, e-mail normal validation for adres, postcode en plaats.
                    if ($('#name').hasClass('verplicht') && $('#name').val() != "") {
                        if (filter.test(email)) {
                            if ($('#adresVeld').hasClass('verplicht') && $('#adresVeld').val() != "") {
                                //Hier zit een postcode filter in voor nederlandse postcodes.
                                if ($('#postcodeVeld').hasClass('verplicht') && $('#postcodeVeld').val() != "" && $('#postcodeVeld').val().match(/^([1-9]\d{3}\s[A-Z]{2})$/)) {
                                    if ($('#plaatsVeld').hasClass('verplicht') && $('#plaatsVeld').val() != "") {
                                        alert("Controleer uw gegevens voordat u verder gaat!");
                                        $("div.hidden").show();
                                        $("#edit").show();
                                        $("#submit").show();
                                        $("#nameShow").hide();
                                        $("#mailShow").hide();
                                        $("#adres").hide();
                                        $("#postcode").hide();
                                        $("#plaats").hide();
                                        $("#click2").hide();

                                        //Geef waardes van ingevulde form aan het nieuwe form
                                        $("#nameUitlees").val(naam);
                                        $("#mailUitlees").val(email);
                                        $("#adresUitlees").val(adres);
                                        $("#postcodeUitlees").val(postcode);
                                        $("#plaatsUitlees").val(plaats);

                                        $("#edit").click(function() {
                                            $("div.hidden").hide();

                                            $("#nameShow").show(naam);
                                            $("#mailShow").show(email);
                                            $("#adres").show(adres);
                                            $("#postcode").show(postcode);
                                            $("#plaats").show(plaats);
                                            $("#click2").show();
                                            $("#edit").hide();
                                            $("#submit").hide();
                                        });

                                        $("#submit").click(function() {
                                            alert("succes");
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        alert("Uw plaats klopt niet!");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    alert("Uw postcode klopt niet!");
                                }
                            } else {
                                alert('Uw adres is leeg of klopt niet!');
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert('Uw email klopt niet!');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Uw naam klopt niet!');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("mail klopt niet");
            }
        } else {
            alert("naam klopt niet");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my html form.

```
<form class="large-6 small-10 form" id="testform1">
    <div id="nameShow">
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Name: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="verplicht" placeholder="Name">
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="mailShow">
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Email: </h3></label>
            <input type="email" id="mail" class="verplicht" placeholder="example@example.com">
        </p>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="volgende" id="click1">
    </p>

    <div id="adres">
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Adres: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="adresVeld" class="verplicht" placeholder="adres">
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="postcode">
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Postcode: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="postcodeVeld" class="verplicht" placeholder="1234 AA">
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="plaats">
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Plaats: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="plaatsVeld" class="verplicht" placeholder="Rotterdam">
        </p>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="controle" id="click2">
    </p>
</form>

<!-- hidden uitlees divjes -->
<form class="large-6 small-10 form" id="checkform">
    <div>
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Name: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="nameUitlees" class="verplicht" readonly>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Email: </h3></label>
            <input type="email" id="mailUitlees" class="verplicht" readonly>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Adres: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="adresUitlees" class="verplicht" readonly>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Postcode: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="postcodeUitlees" class="verplicht" readonly>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <label>
                <h3>Plaats: </h3></label>
            <input type="text" id="plaatsUitlees" class="verplicht" readonly>
        </p>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="pas aan" id="edit">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="verzend" id="submit">
    </p>
</from>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle! It will be help full to give best answer.

Comment: Hope this works. the code works but I don't know how to shorten it.

https://jsfiddle.net/br9603yq/

Comment: Don't use your own regex to validate email addresses. You **will** get it wrong. (And you have gotten it wrong.) Validators have been written for this task, search and use one of them. Better yet, let people enter anything they want as long as it contains an `@` sign. It's their loss if they enter something wrong, you don't need to protect them from themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will change that. I am currently working on a other script with the jquery validation plugin it has a email validation what you told but, my problem there is that I can't get values nor functions are working.